# How would I integrate MPI with C++ classes?

Tags: c++, mpi

Lets say I have a class

```
Vector
```

In this class I have a method to calculate the norm of a vector.

```
Vector a
double Norm = a.norm()
```

I would like to use MPI to distribute this calculation. This is a really trivial case, I know.

But where exctly do i place the commands

```
MPI_Comm_size,MPI_Comm_rank,MPI_Init?
```

MPI_init would go in the main file, i think. But would I have to tell each vector the number of processes available each instantiation?

Comment: John explained how to approach this in MPI. You might be interested in using more high-level distributed data structures, such as [DASH](http://www.dash-project.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, for MPI to be used efficiently, a single data structure does not have MPI features inside it.  Figuring out the size and rank of the MPI communicator is the easy part--the hard part is orchestrating your MPI commands.

In your example the first thing you need to do is Scatter the vector across all the MPI processes.  But imagine something like this:

```
mpi_norm(mpi_add(v1, v2));
```

Here, it would be terribly inefficient to implement individual operations on a data structure--you do not want to collect the result of adding two vectors only to turn around and pump them back out to all the MPI processes again.

With quite a lot of work you could implement the above efficiently by having `mpi_add()` return a proxy object which remembers what the calculation was supposed to be, but only performs it lazily, so the partial results can be left separately on many MPI processes which then combine them into a single vector norm and return that.

But it feels like you may be barking up the wrong tree--if your goal is "Make a good MPI program," you should start top-down, not bottom-up.

Comment: So your suggestion would be to start with Eigen and then distribute the operations by accessing the memory somehow? I am new to Eigen so I will have to look this up

Comment: My suggestion is to start by thinking about what your program needs to do at the top level.  Eigen is one of several good libraries that people use to do math, but whether you should use it depends on lots of things we don't know.

Comment: Basically I want to apply a "new" preconditioner to a Krylov method (MINRES, for instance), in parallel.

Comment: I want to beable to apply block matrix multiplication over, say 5, processes

Comment: Does the entire matrix originate in a single process, or do the blocks already exist in the N processes?

Comment: The matrix would originate in a single process. Just for an explanation, lets say I have a (n*m) x (n*m) matrix. I can see how I would parallelise MINRES. (I would have to learn how to pass chunks of an Eigen matrix between other processes, but I can "see" how it can be done). I suppose I am interested to know how to modularise MPI code? surely applying the preconditoner every time I want to apply it would be really messy if applied "in-line".

Comment: I'd say just write the code any which way first, and see how it goes.  It will probably be a lot more obvious how to refactor once you have it working.  The first step is simply to Scatter the matrix pieces amongst all the processes.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the advice! I felt like just "jumping-in" would not be the best way to go.

Comment: Does a parallel linear algebra library like PETSc not do what you need?